# Just getting null values while passing model data from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've just created a composed model with MVC.NET framework and passing it from my view to the controller and get just null-values:

Models:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class ModelX
    {
        public String attributeX { set; get; }
    }
}

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class ModelY
    {
        public String attributeY { set; get; }
    }
}

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class MyComposedModel
    {
        public ModelX SubModel1 { set; get; }
        public ModelY SubModel2 { set; get; }
    }
}
```

CreateView:

```
@model Repo.Models.MyComposedModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubModel1.attributeX, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubModel1.attributeX, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubModel1.attributeX, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubModel2.attributeY, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubModel2.attributeY, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubModel2.attributeY, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Controller:

```
//... 

public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(MyComposedModel MCM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ModelX modX = new ModelX();

                modX.attributeX = MCM.SubModel1.attributeX;

                db.ModelX.Add(modX);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(MCM);
        }

//...
```

May you can help me to find out where my mistake is. Sorry, I am a newbie. I hope I'm not doing it in a completely wrong way. Best regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you have shown works fine.

Comment: Do not accept answers that have nothing to do with your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class MyComposedModel
    {
        public MyComposedModel()
        {
            SubModel1 = new ModelX();
            SubModel2 = new ModelY();
        }

        public ModelX SubModel1 { set; get; }
        public ModelY SubModel2 { set; get; }
    }
}
```

In case of MVC cannot initialize those submodels automatically.

Comment: Thanks! But it's not helping me completely. Before I was getting the error in line "modX.attributeX = MCM.SubModel1.attributeX;" of my controller class. Now I get the DbUpdateException in line "db.SaveChanges();" still in reason of a null value of my attributeX which is not allowed in the database column definition. Any idea?

Comment: Well, does your "MCM.SubModel1.attributeX" now have a value?

Comment: No it hasn't. :(

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what your "HttpContext.Request.Form" contains?

Comment: Sorry, where can I find the HttpContext.Request.Form?

Comment: I could solve my problem and it was a naming problem. Of course the example on top was just a abstract from my project. But I still don't understand why my code wasn't working. But, fine. Now it does. Still thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is the world does this have to do with the question (the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes the models)